# why do i get a circular import error on whichever module that comes first but not on the second?

Tags: python, importerror

I am making a simple inventory program for college assignment. however i keep getting a circular import error on one of the module. i get the error on the module import that comes first and not on the second. but the strange thing is, if i were to switch the import order, the previous erroneous import works and the previously working import returns an error.

Elaboration:

when running as this, import A has circular import error and import B works fine.

```
import A
import B
```

But if i run the program as this, import B has circular import error and import A works fine

```
import B
import A
```

why is this happening? what is the problem here?

This is the main module.

```
import purchase
import addition

def choices():
    print("Press any of following number for a course of action")
    print("1. To Purchase Bikes")
    print("2. To Add Bikes in the Stock")
    print("3. Exit the program\n")
    value = 0

    while not value in range(1, 5):
        try:
            value = int(input("Enter your desired number: "))
        except:
            print("\n\nPlease enter a valid number between 1-5:\n")

    if value > 3 or value < 1:
        print("\nInvalid Input!! Please select from the given.\n")
        choices()

    elif(value == 1):
        purchase.purBikes()

    elif(value == 2):
        addition.addStock()

    elif(value == 3):
        quit()

choices()
```

The whole program is available here. i know its a lot to look through but i didn't know what parts to remove to make a minimalized reproduceable example.
https://filebin.net/zgr985zo5wao5c0e

Comment: could you please give more information about two modules?

Comment: Because as soon as one *uncaught exception* (this kind of error) occurs, the *program stops completely*. This is **not** a compiler checking over your program for problems. This is actually trying to run the code, until something bad happens and it is no longer possible to proceed.

Comment: In other words: for the same reason that if you put `x` on one line and `y` on the next and save and run that file, you get a `NameError` for `x` but not for `y`.

Comment: is there a way to remove this error?

Comment: If you fix the circular import, then there will be no error. We cannot tell you why there is a circular import, because you have not shown us the part of the code that could cause it - the `import`s *from the other modules*. The actual code of `choices` is not so important (after all, the `import` problem happens before any functions can run). If you are not familiar with circular import problems in general, [please first search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) for information. If you cannot fix the problem yourself, try to create a [mre] and edit or post again.

Comment: Is there a "import addition" in purchase.py and a "import purchase" in addition.py?

Comment: there are no 'import addition' in purchase.py and vice verse. 
@KarlKnechtel sir, could you please look the files.

Comment: But there is a import Main in both files, there is your circular import.

Comment: @Txema the program won't run completely if i remove the 'import main' from the modules, shows `choices not defined` error

Comment: Yes, but still you can't do circular imports. Your code can't work with modules as it is now, because X imports Main and Main imports X. The obvious solution is to move all this code to Main.py, because it is interdependant.

Comment: "could you please look the files" No, we do not consider off-site code here; code to reproduce the problem must be in the question itself. Please re-read [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You have to rethink the design.

addition.py:

```
import Main
def addStock():
    # The 2 last lines
    Main.choices()
    return shipCost
```

A module is a library of reusable components, so they can not depend on some "Main", they must work anyhere, specially on unit tests.

Also, you call addition.addStock() in Main.choices(), so there is a circular call. When does it return shipCost?

Answer (score -1):

First off, your welcome function is not defined(I dont see it if it is)
Second, module purchase doesnt exist publicly so it may be the problem

Comment: the welcome function portion was removed to post it here.
how do you make a module exist publicly?
@Hacai7_

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer] and use the answer section for fully worked answers. If you think information is missing in order to understand the problem correctly, don't try to answer yet. At 50 reputation you can ask for more information in the comment section of the question, and at 3000 reputation you can vote to close questions that are ill formed.